# JS / PHP datetimes & timezones , user comments that expires on a specific datetime

Tags: php, javascript, browser, timezone, webserver

On my app users can posts comments and specify the comment's expire datetime.

The process is simple:

They choose a date and the date is inserted inside DB with the comment by PHP in format (Y-m-d H:m:s).

Then when i visualize comments i put a JS countdown on each one comment.

Countdown is calculated by JS from the current JS datetime until the DB stored expiration_datetime CONVERTED IN JS,and this is for each one comment.

So i'm wondering while, inserting i use PHP, then outputting i use JS, will this produce any problem related to timezones and user's browsers datetime vs server datetime?

in PHP i do:

`$expiration_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');`

in JS i convert :

`var expiration_datetime = new Date(<?php $expiration_datetime[0]?>,<?php $expiration_datetime[1]?>,<?php $expiration_datetime[2]?>,<?php $expiration_datetime[3]?>,<?php $expiration_datetime[4]?>,<?php $expiration_datetime[5]?>,);`

So i'm wondering if converting datetime by JS will produce any kind of problem for users with different timezones, at the end, what you suggest to pay attention on, or to do, for using best practices out there?

**MORE ABOUT:**

i'm thinking that maybe setting server and js fixed timezone for dates and datetimes will be unique for all users coming to site, did you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript Date() object stores dates as an offset of number of milliseconds from the epoch (01/01/1970) so simply constructing the date in the manner you've suggested will take account of the user's timezone.

If you normalise the dates you have stored in your database to GMT then you can adopt a belt and braces approach and use:

```
var expiration_datetime = new Date(Date.UTC(
    <?php $expiration_datetime[0]?>, <?php $expiration_datetime[1]?>,
    <?php $expiration_datetime[2]?>, <?php $expiration_datetime[3]?>,
    <?php $expiration_datetime[4]?>, <?php $expiration_datetime[5]?>,
));
```

Which should indicate to the JS parser that the date information it is receiving is GMT.

Comment: great so using both utc for php and js will be unique for all users all over the globe right? .. hope i understood well

Comment: and then .. is this the right or best approach you're describing?

Comment: Yes, UTC is universal and should disregard timezone and daylight savings.

Take a look at the JS date object on the W3 Schools site:

    http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

since this contains a reasonable explanation of the set of tools available to you to convert the values to/from local time.  You might also benefit from looking at a JS date library (such as Moment.js or XDate.js) since these offer much richer date handling functions (but that all really depends on the scope of your date requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Use unix timestamp and construct date from it using buildin JS Date construnctor:

```
php:  time()
js: new Date(ms)
```

Note: php function returns seconds, js - uses milliseconds. Do not forget to multiply on 1000

Comment: can you explain which is the advantage to do that please?

Comment: NB: i'm not talking about date formats, i'm talking about timezones, i need Y-m-d H:m:s , but if you say to me that unix timestamp fixes all my dubts/problems related to js and php datetimes for each timezone, ok !

Comment: Unix time is universal time (UTC). When you calling Date constructor in JS, browser makes shift hours corresponding client timezone.